# How to generate a web page in JEditorPane from html code

Tags: java, html, jeditorpane

Is there a way to compile html code and display the result in a JEditorPane, similar to the function this website provides: http://www.compileonline.com/try_html5_online.php

Answer (score 0):

This [Example](http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/JEditorPane-Edit-HTML-in-Editor-Pane.html) is the answer of your problem.. just copy the code and run on your compiler